# How to refer paths relative to the theme directory?

Tags: theming

I have a theme called Eternal with the following data in it's **eternal.info** file-

```
name = Eternal
description = A Customized Drupal 7 Theme
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate
```

In the template folder lies the **page.tpl.php**. Under the `/themes/` folder, the address becomes -

`/eternal/templates/page.tpl.php`

There are several lines inside the page.tpl.php that require I define a path for an image, like so-

`<img src="images/facebook_icon.png" alt="image comes here">`

The `/images/` folder is located inside the `/eternal/` folder, so to access it from `/templates/` one would need to travel one level up and then access the `/images/` folder. That would look like this - `/../images/`.

The problem is, I cannot define a link that works in Drupal. And I'm sure the images exist in that directory.

I've tried these-

`<img src="../images/facebook_icon.png" alt="image comes here">`

`<img src="images/facebook_icon.png" alt="image comes here"> <!-- not like this would have worked anyway -->`

`<img src="<?php drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'); ?>/images/facebook_icon.png" alt="image comes here">`

It just shows the alt text in every case. No image. How to accomplish this and what is the recommended and proper way to do this?

Comment: <?php drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'); ?> should be what you need. What's its result/return value?

Comment: When I print it, it returns nothing.

Comment: I can't think of any way that would happen. Clear cache. Try disabling the theme and re-enable it, not that I now how that would help. Double-check your spelling of the theme name in the code, and do other fundamental sanity checks. Last resort, directly debug https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_filename/7

Comment: Is the theme enabled and in use?

Comment: It's a best practice to use background image instead of img element if the image is not part of the content. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image for more detailed explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'); ?>
```

as you've already tried, is the correct way to solve your problem. Notice though that you have to print it out as well, as drupal_get_path will only return the path, not print it for you.

I can't immediately think of any reason why it would not work in your case. Some potential suggestions to try could be

1. Double-check your spelling of the theme name in the code.
2. Clear caches.
3. Try disabling the theme/module and re-enable it.

Failing everything else, you'll need to debug [drupal_get_filename()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_filename/7) directly.

Comment: This worked perfectly: `<?php print drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal'); ?>`

I was missing the `print`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get path to your theme with **$directory** variable which will be available in all your templates.

```
<img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/example.png"/>
```

See [template_preprocess()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7)

If you have multiple *img* elements in your page template you can create a dedicated variable for *page.tpl.php* that will keep path to your images directory.

```
/**
 * Impelements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function eternal_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['images_dir'] = $vars['base_path'] . $vars['directory'] . '/images';
}
```

Now, it looks more clear.

```
<img src="<?php print $images_dir; ?>/example.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to print/echo the output of drupal_get_path() for it to actually appear in your markup. By default it simply returns a PHP string.

```
<img src="<?php print($base_path.'/'.drupal_get_path('theme', 'eternal')); ?>/images/facebook_icon.png" alt="image comes here">
```

Comment: As a side note, your relative paths aren't working because they'd be looking relative to the path of the page being viewed, not to your /templates/ folder.

Comment: You forgot to prefix the path with $base_path variable.

Comment: @Xio You're right; I'm accustomed to working with a site that doesn't have a base path deeper than the document root so I haven't needed to use it. Even so, I forgot to include a leading slash. Edited the answer to make it more universal.

Comment: You should not include a leading slash since it's already present in $path_path variable.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Letharion, [`drupal_get_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) should be your first port of call.

> Returns the path to a system item (module, theme, etc.).

The only reason I have posted this as an answer, rather than just left it at Letharions answer is that I wanted to bring attention to the [System Stream Wrapper](https://drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper) module as well:

> Provides stream wrappers to access module, theme, profile, and library
>   files and directories.

Which means that `theme://eternal/images/example.jpg` would also work with this module enabled.